# Need to connect to two different network ranges same time

Tags: networking, ip, routing, subnet

Here is the story.

my internet connection gateway and my IP goes as 
**GW: 192.168.20.x and IP : 192.168.20.23x**

and if I want to access web mail
**GW: 192.168.100.X and IP 192.168.100.2XX**

and my local area network 
**GW: 192.168.1.23X and IP 192.168.1.25x**

Is there any way that I can access all these networks same time with out changing the IP address and GWs time to time

PS: I have already added some routes but those are not working IDK why

[the routes I add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVw6Y.png)

please explain

Comment: I realize you're trying to hide detailed info, but you can do so without the X X in the IP's because they are Private & not reachable, except if attached to the same network you're on. That Said..if your real address is in 192.168.1.x ... tell us your real IP is 192.168.151.101 & your gateway in that case as 192.168.151.1 .. they aren't really, so you're already protected.  ANYWAY .. please add full detail .. When connecting to the internet, give us your full IP (no x's) the Netmask, and Gateway.  do the same for your other two networks. AND you're completely changing IP's to connect right?

Comment: Also, please give us the real "faked" address for the server you're trying to get to.  With that we can give you better detail to the workings that are happening.  Also, youre not physically disconnecting and then re-connecting your network cable, or re-authenticating to a different access point .. right?

Comment: When you say “local network”, does that mean that the 192.168.20.x and 192.168.100.x gateways are on different network segments that are reachable through your router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to play with the routes if you're under Windows (as it seems to be). Windows handles natively multiple IP configurations for the same network interface.

To do this, open the [Network center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVYDm.png) (not sure about the English name for it), then click on the second link on the left to go into the [network interfaces configuration panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQPdW.png) (same). You might have more interfaces than me, but it's not relevant.

Right-click on the interface where all your networks are connected, then choose "Properties". Here, search for the line "Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)", or something like that. Double-click on that line. In the [new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upd2L.png), click on "Advanced".

In the new window, you will be able to input :

- Your three personal IPs. Either you're using static IPs or DHCP. If you're using DHCP, it should be displayed as "DHCP enabled". In this case, you cannot add IPs and it's fine. Otherwise, simply add your personal IPs.
- The three gateways, one for each network. Difference is, you also have to precise the metric for each one. The metric means the priority of the gateway. The highest will be the default one. So just set the Internet GW to 1000 and the two others to 100. This way, you will always use the Internet GW for your regular browsing, but you'll also be able to access the two other networks normally.

Finally, just click OK, OK again, and OK one last time. You should now be able to access every network at the same time

Comment: AFAIK, that's not entirely right. A more specific route _always_ takes priority over a less specific one, so if you have a route for 192.168.100.0/24 (netmask 255.255.255.0) it will always take priority over the "default gateway" route (0.0.0.0/0, netmask 0.0.0.0). The metric is only taken into account if there are several routes to the same network.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't write it the right way. I meant that if no metric is set, the system won't know what the default gateway is. Setting the highest metric on the internet GW will force the system to use it as the default one.

Comment: That still only makes sense if you have multiple default gateways configured at once... in which case, wouldn't it be simpler to just _not_ do that? After all, those other routes are useless anyway.

Comment: Well, problem is Windows does its own job of setting the metric by default, so you have no control on what gateway becomes the default one. If we don't set metric in this case, he will probably not have any Internet connection because there won't be any default gateway (or Windows will just magically choose one of the three). So, if you don't set any metric, you'll have your multiple default gateways. And I'm not talking about the routes he already set, like I said at the beginning of my post, they are indeed useless and he should remove them. I don't do any direct routes modification here.

Comment: @Doezer do i need to remove the routings 1st this method to work ?

Comment: nevermind it did work but with one change i change the interface metric automatic to 1 IDK what it exactly dose but it worked after that@Doezer

Comment: The value itself is not important as long as it is higher than for the other gateways.